# Using custom JQuery scripts in Zend 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I'm new in `Zend Framework` and I try to deal with some `JS` in my project. I have the following code in my `layout.phtml`:

```
<head>
    <!-- Scripts -->
    <?php echo $this->headScript()->prependFile($this->basePath() . '/js/html5.js', 'text/javascript', array('conditional' => 'lt IE 9',))
                                  ->prependFile($this->basePath() . '/js/jquery.min.js')
                                  ->prependFile($this->basePath() . '/js/bonsai.min.js')
                                  ->prependFile($this->basePath() . '/js/ui-controller.js'); ?>

</head>
```

My `ui-controller.js` contains simple `JQuery` script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert('test);
});
```

The problem is it isn't executed at all... I checked in Firebug in Chrome and my file is linked correctly. HTML code seems to be okay aswell... Can anyone help me?

**[edit]**
I wanted to say that I know I can use `ZendX_JQuery` plugin but I wonder how to use other JavaScript libraries when this one doesn't work...

**[edit 2]**

I get this error in the console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined ui-controller.js:1 GET
>   http://myproject.localhost/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.map 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Any javascript errors on the console?

Comment: Please, check my edit. I don't know why `$` isn't defined. I have 1.10.2 JQuery plugin already included and a link in Firebug seems to be okay...

Comment: I replaced my minimized JQuery with dev version and I still get `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined ui-controller.js:1 GET`. Btw. Where to get .min.map file?

Comment: Could you check the order in which js files are loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the order of your JS files is the issue. Because you are successively calling `prependFile()`, the `ui-controller.js` file will end up first in the HTML source, so it's loading before jQuery. Switch these calls to `appendFile()` instead (or reverse their order) and it should work fine.